# Absolute positioned text is being overlapped by relative positioned text

Tags: html, css

The <span> with class .time is absolute positioned in relative to its parent <p> with class .message-text. The issue arises when the text gets overlapped on span text.
As shown in the image:[image]

How can I adjust the paragraph text so that it doesn't overlapped on span text which is representing time?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #eee;
}

.message {
  background: #00008B;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  color: #ffff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.message-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.message-info {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.message .time {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
}

.chat_rightside {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

#messages {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 25px 25px 0px 25px;
}

.message_name {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="chat_rightside">
    <div id="messages">

      <div class="message">
        <p class="message-info">
          <span class="message_name">USER</span>
        </p>
        <p class="message-text">
          Hello
          <span class="time">19:47</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="message">
        <p class="message-info">
          <span class="message_name">USER2</span>
        </p>
        <p class="message-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, paulo vocibus cum no, eam ape
          <span class="time">19:47</span>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't find any work around to it. Any help will be most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Just adding some padding to the right/bottom of the container would prevent the overlap, but it really depends what sort of style changes you are happy with.

Comment: You could add a max width of the size of time to message-text which would mean you wouldn't need to padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what it does. Absolute text will be independent of other elements.

What you need is to limit the width of the `.message-text` class by either using `width` or adding some padding on the right side of the `.message-text` element.

So it would be something like one of following:

```css
.message-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```css
// Would need to move .time out of .message-text in this case
.message-text {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```